# JSF Mouse Icon changes on mousehover of label (Primefaces)?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have one strange issue on UI. I have been using JSF and PrimeFaces. Whenever i am hovering my mouse on the labels of my fields my mouse icon changes to the one that appears when we click on links. But nothing happens on click. But the change of the mouse icon has been serious concern. Please find below code for one of my fields. Is there any property that i need to add to stop it. Any help much appreciated. THanks.

```
<p:outputLabel  for="contactName" value="Contact Name: " style="font-size:11px;" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="contactName" style="width:150px" value="#{someBean.value}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="All" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Y" itemValue="Y"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="N" itemValue="N"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: adding `style="cursor: default;"` to labels might work as a workaround.

Comment: Are you using some bootstrap styles? I've seen that happening there.

Comment: No bootstrap styles. Am using Primefaces and JSF.

Comment: Inspect the element in some browser and check which style adds some cursor display. Then share the style name here please.